# Where is the "context.window_manager.keyconfigs[0].preferences.select_mouse" in version 3.0?

Tags: mouse

Where is the `context.window_manager.keyconfigs[0].preferences.select_mouse` in version 3.0?

I have updated to Blender Alpha build for v3.0, but my old code no longer works. After reading the new API and release notes, I found nothing. How can I get the mouse select?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Is the idea you want to listen for Left Mouse Button Down?

Comment: i want to know the mouse select mode, left or right